# Lookup inside first field of array of objects MONGO

Tags: php, database, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a dataset in which i want to put lookup inside an `id` that is inside an array of objects . now when i add lookup . it replaces the complete document with the lookup result . Now inside that object i have some other content which i want to access, but it gets replaced. Also i dont want to put `lookup` in all elements of that array of objects just the first one. The main this is i want to `access scale` after the lookup is done

Below is my data-set

```html
"user_id" : ObjectId("5b17b992c440782b5a218cd2"),
        "commission" : [
                {
                        "commissson_id" : ObjectId("5bc05984b49e14243f2973ad"),
                        "scale" : "14"
                },
                {
                        "commissson_id" : ObjectId("5bc05992b49e14243f2973ae"),
                        "scale" : "14"
                },
                {
                        "commissson_id" : ObjectId("5bc05984b49e14243f2973ad"),
                        "scale" : "1"
                },
                {
                        "commissson_id" : ObjectId("5bc0596a414d30243f94b0de"),
                        "scale" : "1"
                }
             ]
```

So far i have tried this

```html
$pipe=[
   [
    '$match'=>
      [
       '_id'=> $user_id
      ],
   ],
   [
    '$lookup'=>
      [
       'from'=>'commission',
       'localField'=>'commission.0.commissson_id',
       'foreignField'=> '_id',
       'as'=> 'commission'
      ]
   ],
 ];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first [**`$unwind`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) aggregation the `commission` array and rollback using [**`$group`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) aggregation

```
[ '$match'=> [ '_id'=> $user_id ]],
[ '$unwind'=> '$commission' ],
[ '$lookup'=> [
  'from'=> 'commission',
  'localField'=> 'commission.commissson_id',
  'foreignField'=> '_id',
  'as'=> 'commission.commission'
]],
[ '$unwind'=> '$commission.commission' ],
[ '$group'=> [
  '_id'=> '$_id',
  'commission'=> [ '$push'=> '$commission' ]
]]
```